# Setup Flink application with multiple different SQL query(aggregation)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, flink-sql

I need to build a pipeline with different column aggregations from a same source, say, one by **userId**, another by **productId**, and etc. I also want to have different granularity aggregations, say, by hourly, daily. Each aggregation will have a different sink, say a different nosql table.

It seems simple to build a SQL query with Table API. But I would like to reduce the operation overhead of managing too many Flink apps. So I am thinking putting all different SQL queries in one pyflink app.

This is first time I build Flink app. So I am not sure how feasible this is. In particular, I'd like to know:

- Read the Flink doc, I see there are concepts of application vs job. So I am curious  if each SQL aggregation query is a single Flink job?
- will the overall performance degraded because of too many queries in one Flink app?
- since the queries share a same source(from kinesis), will each query get a copy of the source. Basically, I want to make sure each event will be processed by each sql aggregation query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple queries into one job if you use a statement set:
https://docs.ververica.com/user_guide/sql_development/sql_scripts.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Btw, do you know what would happen to the source events if there are multiple aggregation pipelines. Say it is a kinesis source, I am concerned that if an event has being processed by one aggregation, then the other aggregation may miss it as they share a same Kinesis consumer ? Or the event will be copied inside Flink for each aggregation pipeline? Thanks